# exit the prompt by `at` command

Tags: shell-script, at

I want to set a cron at a specific time and I am using at for that. However at puts you in a special prompt. Is there a way I can exit the prompt in my code without having to use CTRL + D?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your relevant source code for running "at".

Comment: Why do you need a way other than ctrl+D?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the `at` command from within a shell script you just need to `echo` the commands that should be run at a certain time *into* `at`:

```
echo "echo test > /tmp/at.test" | at now +5min
```

This will execute `echo test > /tmp/at.test` in 5 minutes. Thus, wait 300 seconds and have a look into `/tmp/at.test` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this in the future, you can pres `CTRL+C` to exit the `at` scheduler prompt **without saving**.

If you use `CTRL+D`, then your script will be scheduled and run.